# Facing problem with constraint layout widget in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm facing problem while using constraint layout widget in android studio. I'm new to android studio, so mistakes can happens on my operating too.

My Android Studio version details:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46)
```

a video document to show the problematic situation that I am facing: https://youtu.be/-UIcRBA1qbM

Comment: In my experience as an Android developer, don't use the design view. Just don't. It's unfortunate, but it has always seriously sucked with tons of problems. Google has never gotten it right and never will now that xml is being replaced by compose. Stick to the code or split view, and add the constraints you need in xml.

Comment: @Trevor okay Senior brother, thanks for the Suggestion, I'll follow it for Sure Insha Allah! :)